# Transpose a .csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Well, I need to transpose a .csv file (created by a Get-Content & Select-String uses), with something like this:

```
Date Logged:        09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 666 dph
Date Logged:        10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 0 dph
Date Logged:        10-06-2014 08:07:03 AM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 402 dph
Date Logged:        10-06-2014 11:34:31 AM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 665 dph
Date Logged:        10-23-2014 09:10:41 AM
```

Into something like this:

```
Date Logged:            Task Name:      Nominal Throughput: Date Logged:    
09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM  ALPINE_A06_U1   666 dph             10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM
```

It´s possible to do this with a powershell script? Or maybe a need to change the way to generate csv file?

Comment: My recommendation is to have your original script (the one that uses `Get-Content` and `Select-String`) output custom objects. Then all you have to do is pipe to `Export-Csv` to get a CSV file.

Comment: as `Bill_Stewart` pointed out, you are better served by making a REAL csv file. [*grin*] what you show as the input file is NOT a csv file ... it is just a text file.

Comment: Right. So, I´m trying to create a real .csv file, with `PSCustomObject`, and didn´t goes well. I´ve created an object, but I cannot export to .csv. Where I´m doing it wrong?    `[pscustomobject]@{
TaskName = $taskName
JobThroughput = $JobThroughput

}

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TaskName -Value $taskName
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name JobThroughput -Value $JobThroughput

$obj | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "GetName" -Value {$this.TaskName +' '+$JobThroughput}`

Comment: See my answer for an example of how to output custom objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your example uses 3 lines for each object. Each starts with a label `Date Logged` and ends with label `Nominal Throughput`.

The example however has an extra line `Date Logged` at the end, so I assume that is part of the next object you haven't copied over.

As the value in `Date Logged` contains colon characters, it may be tricky to simply replace the `:` by a `=` character in order to get `ConvertFrom-StringData` to work.

This uses a different approach where only the first `:` in each line is replaced by `=` using `-split` and `-join`

```
$lines=@'
Date Logged:        09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 666 dph
Date Logged:        10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 0 dph
Date Logged:        10-06-2014 08:07:03 AM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 402 dph
Date Logged:        10-06-2014 11:34:31 AM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 665 dph
Date Logged:        10-23-2014 09:10:41 AM
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# or by reading from a file:
# $lines = Get-Content -Path 'TheInputFile'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i += 3) {
    $str = (($lines[$i] -split ':', 2).Trim() -join ' = '),
           (($lines[$i + 1] -split ':', 2).Trim() -join ' = '),
           (($lines[$i + 2] -split ':', 2).Trim() -join ' = ') -join "`r`n"
    [PsCustomObject]($str | ConvertFrom-StringData)
}
```

Output

```
Nominal Throughput Date Logged            Task Name    
------------------ -----------            ---------    
666 dph            09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM ALPINE_A06_U1
0 dph              10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM ALPINE_A06_U1
402 dph            10-06-2014 08:07:03 AM ALPINE_A06_U1
665 dph            10-06-2014 11:34:31 AM ALPINE_A06_U1
                   10-23-2014 09:10:41 AM
```

(the last line shows a partial entry because the object in the example is not 'complete')

<sup>P.S. If you want to keep the same order of properties in the output, change `[PsCustomObject]($str | ConvertFrom-StringData)` into `[PsCustomObject]($str | ConvertFrom-StringData) | Select-Object 'Date Logged', 'Task Name', 'Nominal Throughput'`</sup>

Comment: Yes,  extra line with a single `Date Logged` was a mistake. So, how could I wrote the output? With `out-file` ? Or an `Export` option? It´s not clear for me. And thanks for help me.

Comment: @RafaelLisboa I would do `Export-Csv` on this, since you receive objects. Just capture in a variable like `$result = for ...` and do `$result | Export-Csv -Path <thefile.csv> -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thanks! It clear my mind and help me a lot. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegEx replace to reformat it to be X=Y instead of X: Y, split it up into multi-line strings, and use a combination of `New-Object` and `ConvertFrom-StringData` to do what you're looking for.

```
$RawText=@'
Date Logged:        09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 666 dph
Date Logged:        10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 0 dph
Date Logged:        10-06-2014 08:07:03 AM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 402 dph
Date Logged:        10-06-2014 11:34:31 AM
Task Name:      ALPINE_A06_U1
Nominal Throughput: 665 dph
Date Logged:        10-23-2014 09:10:41 AM
'@
$StringData=$RawText -replace ':\s+','=' -split '(?=Date Logged)'
$StringData|ConvertFrom-StringData|%{New-Object PSObject -Property $_}
```

That outputs:

```
Nominal Throughput Date Logged            Task Name    
------------------ -----------            ---------    
666 dph            09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM ALPINE_A06_U1
0 dph              10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM ALPINE_A06_U1
402 dph            10-06-2014 08:07:03 AM ALPINE_A06_U1
665 dph            10-06-2014 11:34:31 AM ALPINE_A06_U1
                   10-23-2014 09:10:41 AM
```

Comment: Thanks, but, when I´ve tried with all data, this error message appears:  `ConvertFrom-StringData : Data line 'Date Logged:  09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM' is not in 'name=value' format. 
At line:6174 char:13
+ $StringData|ConvertFrom-StringData|%{New-Object PSObject -Property $_ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand`. I don´t know what it is.

Comment: I had assumed that your whitespace was spaces, not tabs. I have updated my answer to better accommodate that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example script that outputs custom objects containing the data in your question:

```
[PSCustomObject] @{
  "Date Logged"        = "09-29-2014 02:17:45 PM"
  "Task Name"          = "ALPINE_A06_U1"
  "Nominal Throughput" = "666 dph"
}

[PSCustomObject] @{
  "Date Logged"        = "10-03-2014 04:52:09 PM"
  "Task Name"          = "ALPINE_A06_U1"
  "Nominal Throughput" = "0 dph"
}

[PSCustomObject] @{
  "Date Logged"        = "10-06-2014 08:07:03 AM"
  "Task Name"          = "ALPINE_A06_U1"
  "Nominal Throughput" = "402 dph"
}

[PSCustomObject] @{
  "Date Logged"        = "10-06-2014 11:34:31 AM"
  "Task Name"          = "ALPINE_A06_U1"
  "Nominal Throughput" = "665 dph"
}
```

If you save this as a script file, you can run it and pipe its output to `Export-Csv` and get a CSV file.